# Параллельные процессы в c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sql-server, framework

Есть задача: читать из таблицы в бд ms SQL некоторую колонку с путями к файлам и копировать их по заданному адресу. Если решать все последовательно, то все элементарно: считать из бд данные в какой-нибудь список, а потом выполнить копирование. Но на мой взгляд это не рационально, ведь таблица может быть здоровенной и очень много полезного времени в холостую. Подскажите, как можно реализовать параллельный алгоритм вида: взять топ 100 записей из таблице, кинь в очереди в методе копирования, пока копирование идет извлечь еще100 записей и пополнить очередь.
Может быть сможете привести примеры чего-нибудь похоже или классы, которые мне понадобятся или статьи с примерами?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стал делить на пакеты по 100 файлов, а реализовал бы с помощью `ConcurrentQueue`. Одна задача вычитывает имена файлов, заполняя очередь, другая её разбирает. Та, которая разбирает, создаёт некоторое ограниченное (с помощью `SemaphoreSlim`) количество задач копирования.

Примерная реализация в консольном приложении:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    static ManualResetEvent evtFileQueued = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    static SemaphoreSlim sem = null;
    static Task tQueueFill = null;

    static void Main()
    {
        int MaxCopyTasks = Math.Max(1, Environment.ProcessorCount - 2);
        sem = new SemaphoreSlim(MaxCopyTasks);

        tQueueFill = QueueFill();
        tQueueFill.Start();
        Task tQueueProcess = QueueProcess();
        tQueueProcess.Start();

        Task.WaitAll(tQueueFill, tQueueProcess);

        while (sem.CurrentCount < MaxCopyTasks)
            Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    static async Task QueueFill()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("...");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FileName from TableName", connection);

        using (var dr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                queue.Enqueue((string)dr[0]);
                evtFileQueued.Set();
            }
    }

    static async Task QueueProcess()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (tQueueFill.IsCompleted || tQueueFill.IsFaulted || tQueueFill.IsCanceled)
                break;

            if (!evtFileQueued.WaitOne(250))
                continue;

            while (!queue.IsEmpty)
            {
                if (!await sem.WaitAsync(0))
                    break;

                string fileName = null;
                if (queue.TryDequeue(out fileName))
                {
                    Task tCopy = new Task(CopyFile, fileName);
                    tCopy.Start();
                }
                else
                    sem.Release();
            }

            if (queue.IsEmpty)
                evtFileQueued.Reset();
        }
    }

    static void CopyFile(object param)
    {
        string fileName = (string)param;
        string fileNameDest = Path.Combine("Directory", fileName);
        File.Copy(fileName, fileNameDest);
        sem.Release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OrdinalPartitioner<MyItem> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(items);

IList<IEnumerator<MyItem>> paritions = partitioner.GetPartitions(
    Environment.ProcessorCount);

Task[] tasks = partitions.Select(p => Task.Run(() => { 
        using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
        using (p)
        while (p.MoveNext())
        {
            MyItem current = p.Current;

            ctx.DoSomething1(current);
            ctx.DoSomething2(current);
        }
    })).ToArray();
```

[Partitioner Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.aspx)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что будет массив задач, в моем случае элементом массива будет являться сочетание двух задач извлечь скопировать, потом я все это кидаю в какой-нибудь параллельный цикл и запускаю на исполнение?